# Meteor: Creating a single CMS form

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

So I am having difficulty creating a single form that, when updated, updates HTML text.

For example, on page 1 of my site, there is a form with the words ***TITLE*** written in it. Now on page 2 the only words on the page are ***TITLE***. Now I want to be able to update that form to now say ***TITLE 2*** and have is update page 2 instantly.

I want to make lots of these forms so what is the way to do this with the least amount of code?

Comment: We need some more information. Do you have any existing code? If so, add it to your question.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Have you read and tried tutorials?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form and the element showing your text are in different template, you have to use **Session**.

**In your first template (page 1):** Attach an event to your input so when you type text you update the Session variable.

**In your second template (page 2):** Use a simple helper returning the value of the Session variable

Here's the code:

```
<template name="page1">
    <input type="text" class="js-change-text">
</template>

Template.page1.events({
    "keyup .js-change-text"(event, instance) {
        let inputValue = event.target.value);
        Session.set('inputValue', inputValue);
    },
});

<template name="page2">
    <h1>{{getInputValue}}</h1>
</template>

Template.page2.helpers({
    getInputValue() {
        return Session.get('inputValue');
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for and worked great!